# How to configure ssh to load more private keys automaticaly?

Tags: ssh, sshd

How does ssh look for private key to load?

I know that it does try to load `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and after this `~./.ssh/id_dsa`.

Now I do have two keys. Is it possible to name them in such way that ssh will pick them up directly?

If not, would it be possible to trick it, and put the second key inside `id_dsa` file, even if it is an `rsa` key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If a SSH agent is running, *ssh* tries all keys loaded into the agent.
- If an `-i file` option is given, *ssh* uses the specified key.
- If `IdentityFile` is set in the command line or in `~/.ssh/config`, *ssh* uses the specified key. (You can specify the keys per hostname or domain. See the *`ssh_config(5)`* manual page.)
- Otherwise, it uses a hardcoded list {`id_ecdsa`, `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`} in the `~/.ssh` directory.

Out of these, *ssh-agent* might be the most convenient option – it also removes the need to unlock the private key every time. Use `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa` to load a key. If an agent is not running, start it with `exec ssh-agent bash` or using such tools as [Keychain](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml). (Normally, such environments as GNOME, Unity or Mac OS X should start an agent automatically.)

If you decide against using *ssh-agent*, and you need to use different keys for different machines, you can edit `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host one.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_one
Host two.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_two
Host *.foo.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_foo.org
```

---

Note that the file name has absolutely no meaning to *ssh*; it will treat both `id_dsa` and `id_asdfghjk` identically. This means that you *can* name a RSA key `id_dsa`. However, it will not accept two keys in a single file.

Comment: I personally like my SSH keys named after the doors they open -- `username-server_ed25519`.